# How to use bluetooth on a raspberry pi using Azure IoT Edge to connect to mobile app?

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, azure-iot-edge

I am currently working on a project evolving a mobile app to be able to connect on a raspberry pi's IoT Edge module over bluetooth to control & monitor telemetry data.
I know about IoT Edge, developing on raspi and someone else developing the mobile app, but how to develop the Edge module with bluetooth? How to tell the module to wait for someone to connect to the raspi over bluetooth to communicate with it?

Thanks for your time guys.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  What have you tried so far?  What errors did you get?

Comment: Thanks! Actually I have not tried anything, still trying to push images to ACR, docker's is b*tch. I have found some NuGet packages for bluetooth, but still trying to figure out for my specific usage.I have not published that question because I had errors, just to ask people if someone may have tried it before

Comment: The thing is, I can't manage to build my bluetooth module, as I am using 32feet nuget package, that seems to need .NET framework 4.6.1, I have installed it (dev/target pack) and checked it on VS Installer and restarted computer, but it keeps telling me that it can't find v4..1 when building module (Error: MSB3644)

Comment: Check the suggestions outlined here and see if it helps: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e1dde60a-88f9-40e9-9eab-97bf3248600f/how-to-use-bluetooth-on-a-raspberry-pi-using-azure-iot-edge-to-connect-to-mobile-app?forum=iotedge